# Errors playing YouTube content from within an Android Webview on Google TV

Tags: android, google-tv

I have a requirement to play YouTube video content from within an Android application on Google TV. Specifically, we'd like to play it from within a Webview inside a Google TV app. This works on Honeycomb devices (3.1), but does not work on GTV.

Here is the video we are testing with, and how we are linking it via a URL that is loaded into a Webview:

```
<iframe class="youtube-player" type="text/html" width="400" height="285" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/u1zgFlCw8Aw" frameborder="0">
```

The page we are loading in the Webview also WORKS fine when using the regular Browser app (the video plays there, embedded via an iframe, just fine!).

Here are the Webview settings that we are using:

```
  web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
  web.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
```

When loading the same URL that works in the Browser app from our own app, via a Webview,  it fails. The screen shows the initial YouTube video in the box with the controls, but when play is pressed the box turns to plain black and no video plays. SOMETIMES audio plays, but never video.

Logcat shows:

> E/libEGL(14956): call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread) 
>   D/ShaderProgram(14956): couldn't load the vertex shader!

I did find an open bug report with another user having the same problem (http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=22018) , but there is no follow up there, so I thought I would see if SO gets more attention. Does anyone have any more insight about this issue?

thanks

Comment: Are you on a Sony or a Logitech box.  I suspect you can get it to work on a Sony, but not logitech as the v2.1 aka HC 3.2 release supports video in a WebView.

Comment: Try:

http://code.google.com/p/html5webview/

Comment: I was trying on the Logitech, will check the Sony though. Thanks for the help on both fronts guys!

Comment: I finally got around to trying on the Sony, inside a WebView, and it fails there too -- different error messages but still fails (I originally thought it was working, but I was using the same web page outside a WebView when it worked, and got confused -- inside a WebView it fails). According to this page, it's just not supported: https://developers.google.com/tv/android/articles/moving_web_content_to_android (it's part of what's missing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been working on a solution to the same problem. It is working on both tablets and Google TV (including the revue).

The major difference from your code is that I create the HTML code in the android app in code and pass this to webView.loadDataWithBaseURL

```
        webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("http://www.youtube.com", html, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

For more details, please see the source I am working on:

http://code.google.com/p/android-reddittv/source/browse/trunk/RedditTV%20HD%20Android/src/com/elsewhat/reddittv/hd/YoutubePlayerActivty.java

Comment: And, I am so installing RedditTV when I get a chance too, great app concept.

Comment: I haven't had time to try the creation of the HTML from Java and injecting into the webview the way you're doing with reddittv dparnas, but I looked over the code and it seems logical. Since you say it works on the Revue, and I'm lame for not being able to test it sooner, I'll accept. Thanks.

Comment: This requires the cumbersome step of generating HTML for the WebView myself.  I'd much rather reuse YouTube's HTML code in the WebView instead of writing it myself.

Comment: @IgorG. As far as I see it, if you want to get events from the youtube player into an Android Activity, you need to inject some javascript code. This code is needed to define the proxy object and methods between javascript and the activity.